# n{X,Y} quantifier not working with braces in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

```
>>> patt = new RegExp("[a-z]{1,5}")
RegExp /[a-z]{1,5}/
>>> patt.test("yo")
true
>>> patt.test("")
false
>>> patt.test("yoyoyoyo")
true
>>> patt.test("yoyoyAAAAoyo")
true
```

What I would expect from [a-z]{1,5} is to match one to five lowercase characters, yet it seems to be matching anything it is given except for nulls. Am I missing something? Does JS support quantifiers for brackets at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're forgetting that "yoyoyoyo" **contains** a string of between one and five characters.

If you want to match complete strings only, you have to anchor the regex:

```
var regex = /^[a-z]{1,5}$/;
```

The `.test()` function means, "can this pattern be found in the search string?". (Or as Ruby people would say, "can you find this needle in that haystack?").

Comment: Why would only Ruby people use the needle in a haystack analogy? bit programmerist

Comment: @RoryPicko92 I don't know for sure; I just always have seen it in Ruby or Rails-oriented contexts. I live a pretty sheltered life so I'm probably wrong :) There's nothing wrong with that analogy of course.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to test *exactly* that regular expression, you must put the start (`^`) and end (`$`) delimiters:

```
var patt = new RegExp("^[a-z]{1,5}$")
patt.test("") // false
patt.test("yo") // true
patt.test("yoyoy") // true
patt.test("yoyoyo") // false
```

Otherwise it will just check if any part of your string matches your regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for it in the middle of the string, this will work.
If not, use the ^$ anchors as everyone suggests.

```
 #  /(?:^|[^a-z])([a-z]{1,5})(?=[^a-z]|$)/     

 (?: ^ | [^a-z] )
 ( [a-z]{1,5} )
 (?= [^a-z] | $ )
```